função em C para validar e-mail passado como argumento
Boa tarde a todos.
Estou com dificuldades para terminar esta função(validarEmail). O Problema está no uso da função strcat, pois ela serve para concatenar duas strings, e o que quero no lugar de strcat() é uma função(concatenarChar()) que concatene um caractere numa string(e_mail) até o final do e-mail passado e então comparar com as constantes(hotmail, yahoomail, etc...).
Desde já agradeço a atenção.
Segue o código:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void concatenarChar(char* string, char caractere){

}

int validarEmail(const char *email){
    int cont;
    int validado = 0;
    char e_mail[14];
    const char* hotmail   = "@hotmail.com";
    const char* yahoomail = "@yahoo.com.br";
    const char* gmail     = "@gmail.com.br";

    for(cont = 0; cont < strlen(email); cont++){
         if(email[cont] == '@'){
             for(int cont2 = cont + 1; cont2 < strlen(email); cont2++){ 
                 strcat(e_mail, email[cont2]);
             }

         if(!strcmp(e_mail, hotmail) ||
            !strcmp(e_mail, yahoomail) ||
            !strcmp(e_mail, gmail)){
            validado = 1;

            break;
         }           
         }
 }

return validado;

}

Importante você [edit] sua pergunta convertendo o código em um [mcve] do problema, explicar como tentou resolver e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.
